# 20GB SQL Server DataBase Backup resore

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL server data backup size is above 20 GB. My database is in E drive have enough space but my SQL software installed in C drive which has low memory. In this scenario how can i restore my backup to E drive.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:Detach DB**

```
USE MASTER;
GO
ALTER DATABASE DBName
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
```

-- Detach DB

```
EXEC MASTER.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'DBName'
GO
```

**Step 2:**
Now move the files from C drive to E drive. You can now reattach the files with E drive.

Comment: My database physical path is in e drive. and I want to restore database 20gb while my c drive has only 9 gb

Comment: Please check some solutions their http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34248/restore-backup-fails-not-enough-disk-space

Answer (score 0):

```
USE MASTER;
GO
ALTER DATABASE DBName
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
-- Detach DB
EXEC MASTER.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'DBName'
GO
```

Comment: you can merge these two answers into one

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore database via SQL Server Management Studio.
While restoring , you can specify `MDF` and `LDF` file location to your `E:` drive.

> To specify the new location of the database files, select the Files
>   page, and then click Relocate all files to folder. Provide a new
>   location for the Data file folder and Log file folder

[**THIS MIGHT HELP**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186390.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

steps :

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET OFFLINE;
```

Move the file or files to the new location.
For each file moved, run the following statement.

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name MODIFY FILE ( NAME = logical_name, FILENAME = 'new_path\os_file_name' );
```

Run the following statement.

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET ONLINE;
```

Verify the file change by running the following query.

```
    SELECT name, physical_name AS CurrentLocation, state_desc  
FROM sys.master_files  
WHERE database_id = DB_ID(N'<database_name>');
```

for more details go through [url](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345483.aspx)